# button does not react on click despite having implemented click listeneers

Tags: android

I am scratching my head over this and really can't think what I did wrong. I have implemented a button in my main activity layout as per below:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@string/calculate"
    android:textSize="13sp" />
```

in my main activity I hooked this button to a button listener as per below:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);        
button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
```

which calls my button listener:

```
private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

    }
};
```

on click the button fails to start the other activity, which I have duly declared in the Android manifest...

when I tap on the button I can in debug mode I can see the following entry into the LogCat:

```
04-27 19:06:31.402: D/GestureDetector(25925): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
```

Any idea on this problem? any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks pretty straightforward. Have you set a breakpoint in the onclick(View v) method to see if its hitting it?

Comment: your putting Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);        
button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener); before setContentView() or after it.

Comment: @rickky if he has done it button would be null.

Comment: @rickky I have made sure that setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); is right at the beginning of the main, but it did not help :(

Comment: @blackbelt that's what i asked him..

Answer (score 0):

try to declare

```
      private class clicker implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

and then

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);        
        button.setOnClickListener(new clicker());
```

instead of new OnClickListener .Does it work?

Comment: if I declare a new class, how can then call this from the main?

Comment: at the moment I have button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);

Comment: the class can be declared inside Your main. This is called an inner class. Then do it like I wrote with button.setOnClickListener(new Clicker());

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work: @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
  button.setOnClickListener(new Clicker());
 }

Comment: ok, I think to get rid of this, please post Your complete Main.Java code and Your main.xml code, so we could see more and maybe find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have used any gesture detector to convert swipe into event ,then that is what makeing this error happen ,try to comment out the gesture listner code and then run it .

It will work as charm .

Comment: I had not idea I had implemented a gesture detector so I don't know what this looks like in the code... I presume this was automatically implemented when I've added a sliding drawer in my layout?

Comment: how can I locate this gesture detector?

Comment: could not find any gesture code... so this is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Is your button a child view of some parent view or layout? It is possible that the click event has been consumed by the parent layout. Try set your button to

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: I have added this property to the button, but no joy:                 <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="@string/calculate"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:clickable="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

Comment: Did you customize any gesture methods in your class, like responding differently to a swipe or touch event?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you may tried to access a view, which the *layout is actually inflated on some another view or activity*, may be inflated by an adapter, for a listview. Check that the layout you inflated is correct, and try again.